WireGuard VPN always working from a US connection, but occasionally not from an Asian-based connection?
What might be the issue here and how might it be troubleshooted/fixed?
I have a WireGuard VPN in a home lab in the US. It appears to work when connecting from the United States, when my US connection is working and I have a friend try to connect from Asia, the connection from Asia will sometimes work and sometimes not work.
When the connection fails, it says in Asia that the DNS cannot be resolved, but trying to put in a Google IP address directly also fails.
This is regardless of whether we are both connected to the VPN or at different times.
Sometimes this appears to be fixed when the computer in Asia is restarted or if it waits several hours and retries again.
We've tried allowing all IPs or changing the MTU in the preconfigured wireguard client tunnel files, but this doesn't seem to have any effect.
This issue will come up in Asia, and I'll access in the US and have no problem. I have also been connected to the VPN first and then had Asia have issues. Most of the time the connect works with one or both clients connected.
When the connection is not working in Asia, connections to other wireguard services (e.g. Windscribe) appear to be working, as is the internet connection to sites without using a VPN.
Update: It seems like restarting the Mac computer in Asia magically makes the VPN connection work again?
Configuration
Server

WireGuard VPN installed using: https://github.com/angristan/wireguard-install.
Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS with the latest updates as of 2024-09
Uses Cloudflare for DDNS: https://github.com/timothymiller/cloudflare-ddns

US Client

MacPro ~2018
Mac WireGuard Client: https://www.wireguard.com/install/

Asia Client

MacPro ~2020
Mac WireGuard Client: https://www.wireguard.com/install/


what is a Google IP address? are you using a google server to host wireguard?

@JaromandaX Server is hosted in my basement. We used a google.com IP address as one to test if it was DNS was not working. E.g. we used nslookup.io to find the address: 142.250.189.238

Oh, so DNS fails - perhaps your configuration is wrong

Not just the DNS failing though. Putting in the direct IP address still fails in Asia but works in the US.

perhaps your configuration is wrong

Still fails in Asia even when using essentially the same credentials file at the US client.

the whole of Asia?

@JaromandaX right now I have someone trying it in the Philippines. Interestingly enough, I set up a tailscale exit node on the exact same device running wireguard and we don't have any problem with that node when the wireguard doesn't work.
In fact, I've now had the same issues above with https://github.com/wg-easy/wg-easy, and it is "fixed" by "touching" the UI dashboard - e.g. I go in and open the page on the local network. When the person in PH does this via the tailscale node, it also fixes the issue? Scratching my head on this one.
